ViewModel Import problem in Android Studio
My code
i tried using the exact import used in tutorial but that also did not work. i dont know if this is because I am using  the older version of android studio ie android hegehog right now .
import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel
import

Please include your dependencies list

try adding these dependencies in your build.gradle.kts file then sync the project:
val lifecycle_version = "2.8.3"
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version")
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodelcompose:$lifecycle_version")


I tried but nothing happened.

try changing :
val recipeViewModel: MainViewModel = viewModel()
to :
val recipeViewModel by viewModels()

i tried it but nothing happened

can you share the code ?

Make sure gradle is not in offline mode and sync with internet connection and recheck gradle dependencies
